# Difference between "one of the states" and "the one of states"

Tags: articles, prepositional-phrases

I have a question about the following:

1. Texas is only one of **the** states that still *have* sizable wheat production.
2. Texas is **the** only one of states that still *has* sizable wheat production.

I want to know whether the above construction is true. If so, what is the rule?

Answer (score 2):

I've used braces to emphasize the sense.

1. Texas is one of the {**states** that still **have** sizable wheat production}.

You are selecting Texas from a group of states, those that grow a lot of wheat.  The relative clause modifies the plural noun "states," so its verb must be the plural "have."

2. Texas is the {**one**} of [all the] states {that still **has** sizable wheat production}.

In this case, Texas is the only state to grow a lot of wheat, so the relative clause has to modify the singular "one," so its verb must be the singular "has."

Comment: @dearat  so  in statement 1, the relative pronoun "that" refers to "states", whereas in statement 2, it refers to "Texas". right?

Comment: I'd say "modifies," but yes.  In the second, it refers to "one," which is the same thing as Texas in the sentence.  We can clear up all this confusion by giving Texas back to Mexico.

Comment: In the case of 1. I believe you could get away with either *has* or *have*. It seems to me a moot point as to whether the relative clause modifies *Texas* or *states*.

Comment: Of course, Opie edited and completely changed the sentences in question.